# SQL Query to check not repeated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. I wanted to know, How to check the entries which are not repeated for the other entries.

Better I give one example.

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 3 |

I want output as

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| c | 4 |

because c does not have 4, but the other values a and b do.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? The answer may heavily depend on this. Always tag SQL requests with the DBMS in question.

Comment: Regarding your edited version, what is the expected output if  (a,3) and (b,2) rows are excluded?

Comment: @MANOHAR N: If you appreciate the advice, why don't you follow it? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySql

Comment: Okay, I've added the `mysql` tag to your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for missing entries. For these to find, you must know which entries you expect. You expect to find one entry for all combinations of column1 values and column2 values. You get these with a cross join.

Now you want to select all these pairs **except** for those already in the table. You can use `EXCEPT` for this or `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. You haven't told us your DBMS, so I don't know what it features.

### EXCEPT

```
select c1.column1, c2.column2
from (select distinct column1 from mytable) c1
cross join (select distinct column2 from mytable) c2
except
select column1, column2
from mytable
order by column1, column2;
```

### NOT IN

```
select c1.column1, c2.column2
from (select distinct column1 from mytable) c1
cross join (select distinct column2 from mytable) c2
where (c1.column1, c2.column2) not in
(
    select column1, column2 from mytable
)
order by c1.column1, c2.column2;
```

### NOT EXISTS

```
select c1.column1, c2.column2
from (select distinct column1 from mytable) c1
cross join (select distinct column2 from mytable) c2
where not exists
(
    select null
    from mytable
    where mytable.column1 = c1.column1
    and mytable.column2 = c2.column2
)
order by c1.column1, c2.column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided columns are not nullable

```
select distinct column1
from mytable t1
where exists (
      select 1 
      from mytable t2
      where t2.column2 <> t1.column2
          and t1.column1 not in (
             select t3.column1 
             from mytable t3
             where t3.column2 = t2.column2
             )
      )
```

Comment: is that select 1 or select * in 4th line?

Comment: @MANOHARN  .. select 1. It makes no difference what is selected with EXISTS (SELECT ..) so using 1 as a simplest selection.